# Duplicate selected row in Vertica Database

Tags: sql, vertica

I have been asked to duplicate a specific row in a table. For this I used a simple SQL statment:

```
insert into xyz_tablename(x,y) select * from xyz_tablename where x = "something";
```

However, this statement copies all the row present where x = "something" which is like multipling the selected row by 2.

What I want is to control via counter the number of rows to be duplicated. Is there any function/procedure for this in Vertica?

Now what I have done uptil now:

1. Studied about function (I have understood this, however I cannot use this for this problem).
2. Studied about procedures (Have studied, but cannot understand how to make that bash file).
3. Learnt that there are no for-while loop in vertica.

Anyone can help me with this problem? I hope I am clear. Let me know if I am missing something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*this statement copies all the row present*" - no, it doesn't. It copies only those rows with `x = "something"`. If you don't want to copy all of them, adjust your where clause. Btw: `"something"` is a column name, not a character constant. Character values have to be enclosed in single quotes, so it should be `x = 'something'`

Comment: I meant the same thing man! I am going to correct this. Is there any way I can keep a counter on the number of rows copied? For instance, "I want 5 time this row to be copied". Is this possible?

Comment: Does Vertica have Postgres' `generate_series()` function?

Comment: I will look into it. What does this function do?

Comment: I "generates" rows. This can be used with a cross join to "multiply" the rows from the select: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a4470/1

Comment: The condition which is generating multiple rows, you can put `limit` or `partition by` to get the desired row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below :

```
create table mystore.xyz_tablename(
    x varchar (10)
    ,y INT
    )
    ;

INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,1);
INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,2);
INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,3);
INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,4);
INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,5);
INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,6);
INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,7);
INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename VALUES('abc' ,8);

select * from mystore.xyz_tablename;

mystore_owner=>     select * from mystore.xyz_tablename;
  x  | y 
-----+---
 abc | 1
 abc | 2
 abc | 3
 abc | 4
 abc | 5
 abc | 6
 abc | 7
 abc | 8
(8 rows)

INSERT INTO mystore.xyz_tablename(x,y) 
SELECT a.* 
FROM (SELECT * from mystore.xyz_tablename where y = 8 LIMIT 1) a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT y FROM mystore.xyz_tablename LIMIT 5) b 
ON (1=1)
;

 OUTPUT 
--------
      5
(1 row)


mystore_owner=> select * from mystore.xyz_tablename;
  x  | y 
-----+---
 abc | 1
 abc | 2
 abc | 3
 abc | 4
 abc | 5
 abc | 6
 abc | 7
 abc | 8
 abc | 8
 abc | 8
 abc | 8
 abc | 8
 abc | 8
(13 rows)
```

Let us know if this works for your requirement .

The number of copies can be controlled via the limit clause which is now 5 , you can alter that to your wish . But you can select from other table also which has more rows . If the source table has < than clause then it will fail.

Comment: BEST! Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @user4618280 , you can mark the answer as correct for other users who follow .

Comment: However, this is only working on the condition when the number of rows present in the table is greater than the number of row I want to replicate. For example, if I have one row, and I want to copy it 10 times, this statement won't work. It will work if I have 10 rows present and I want to copy 10 rows.

Comment: Can you explain me, what is a. and b in the query?